# Why the length of IP address is fixed?

Tags: ip, ip-address

Is there technically reason for the fact that the length of IP address need be fixed? Now IPv4 address is 32 bits and IPv6 128 bits.

If IP address doesn't need fixed length, we would can structure IPs hiearchy infinite, right?
Think: 
0
01
011
02
021
022
0223
0224
0225
to infinite...

!!!NOTE: I don't ask, why IPv4 is 32 bits or IPv6 128. I ask, why fixed length? Please, reopen.

Comment: IP was designed for simplicity, especially in the routers (working with the experience from NCP). Arbitrary-length addresses would have added significant complexity.

Comment: How can it be so complexity? Just give non-fixed variable for IP address. Are you sure, this is the only reason?

Comment: Just look at the simple address masking and routing algorithms that IP uses. Then try to reformulate them using addresses of arbitrary length (with a hard limit of what?). It's much easier to use a longer, yet fixed-length address, e.g. 128 bit.